# How to use irreducibility here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$($n\le 2015$) such that $A^{2017}=I_n$. Prove that $A=I_n$.
I think that this should be solved using the fact that the polynomial $f(x)=x^{2017}-1$ rewrites as $f(x)=(x-1)(x^{2016}+x^{2015}+...+1)$ and $x^{2016}+x^{2015}+...+1$ is irreducible, but I don't know how to proceed.
EDIT: The problem linked in the comments doesn't really help me because it doesn't solve the case when $n\le 2015$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I am not an equivalent of the user you linked and my question is not a duplicate of the one you linked.

Comment: Your question is answered in the duplicate, by the OP himself, using the minimal polynomial. This is  the same as lhf has answered:)

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't really clear to me how OP went about using the minimal polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ has degree at most $n \le 2015$.

Since it divides $x^{2017}-1=\Phi_1(x)\Phi_{2017}(x)$, it must be $\Phi_1(x)=x-1$.

Here, $\Phi_m$ is the $m$-th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: Thank you! Does the matrix have to be rational? Couldn't it be real?

Comment: It could not be real because the rotation of the plane by $2\pi/2017$ has a real matrix.

Comment: @lhf you mean *does not have* a real matrix, right?

Comment: It cannot have general real entries if you want to prove that $A=I$.